# Proving Completeness Relation for Dirac Spinors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

So the problem I'm attempting is:
[image]

And I'm trying to verify the completeness relations (2nd two equations).

**Attempt**

So $u_{r}(\mathbf{p})=\sqrt{E+m} \begin{pmatrix}\chi_{r}\\ \frac{\mathbf{\sigma .p}}{E+m}\chi_{r} \end{pmatrix}$ and  $\overline{u}_{r}(\mathbf{p})=u_{r}^{\dagger}\gamma^{0}=\sqrt{E+m} \begin{pmatrix}\chi_{r}^{\dagger} & \frac{\mathbf{\sigma .p}}{E+m}\chi_{r}^{\dagger} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\Bbb{1}_{2} & 0 \\ 0 & -\Bbb{1}_{2}\end{pmatrix}$

Where r=1,2 and $\chi_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ $\chi_2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ as given by my notes (and $1_{2}$ is the 2x2 identity matrix).

Starting with $\chi_{1}\overline{\chi}_{1}$
$=(E+m)\begin{pmatrix}\chi_{1}\\ \frac{\mathbf{\sigma .p}}{E+m}\chi_{1} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\chi_{1}^{\dagger} & \frac{\mathbf{\sigma .p}}{E+m}\chi_{1}^{\dagger} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\mathbb{1}_{2} & 0 \\ 0 & -\mathbb{1}_{2}\end{pmatrix}$

Mulitplying gives:

$=(E+m)\begin{pmatrix}\chi_{1}\\ \frac{\mathbf{\sigma .p}}{E+m}\chi_{1} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\chi_{1}^{\dagger} & -\frac{\mathbf{\sigma .p}}{E+m}\chi_{1}^{\dagger} \end{pmatrix}$

Now I can't multiply through any further and I'm stuck.

Comment: It's going to become a matrix, write $\chi_1$ as a column vector and multiply the components in the obvious way and you'll get a 4x4 matrix.

Comment: So this part is an outer product then? That's annoying, there wasn't anything to suggest it was an outer product